# Split Stereo Input Device to 2 separate Mono Input Devices

Tags: windows-10, audio, virtualization, stereo, mono

I have a Focusrite Scarlet Solo 3rd Gen that I am using to connect my microphone and console audio from my monitor so I can have all my audio in one place. It sends the audio as an input to Windows 10 as a single stereo input that has both inputs on their own side. Is there any program that can split that stereo input into 2 mono inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You could use virtual mixing software like [ASIO Link Pro](https://discuss.cakewalk.com/index.php?/topic/3519-odeus-asio-link-now-available-free/) or [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/potato.htm), to route the two separate channels to separate virtual audio devices.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could explore [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/)

I'm not 100% sure but I think [Elgato WAVE Link](https://help.elgato.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043289491-Elgato-Wave-Link-Release-Notes?_ga=2.194916013.1464827260.1626448073-1850403189.1625748390) has software support so it can work with non-elgato devices.